# Error in predicting raster with Hmsc package in R

Tags: r, terra, mcmc

## Description:

I am trying to predict values in a raster using the Hmsc package in R. I have followed the example in the package's vignette for univariate analysis, but when I attempt to predict on a raster, I encounter the following error:

```r
Error in sam$Beta : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

### Reproducible exaple

I have been using the Hmsc package, and it has excellent features, however, as a user of usual SDM package, I cant figure out how to make predictions to rasters or more clearly SpatRaster, to make it very simple I have used the example in their [first vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmsc/vignettes/vignette_1_univariate.pdf).

So this would be fitting the model:

```r
library(Hmsc)

set.seed(1)

n = 50
x = rnorm(n)

XData = data.frame(x = x)

alpha = 0
beta = 1

L = alpha + beta*x

y = 1*(L+ rnorm(n, sd = 1)>0)

Y=as.matrix(y)

nChains = 2

thin = 5
samples = 1000
transient = 500*thin
verbose = 500*thin


m = Hmsc(Y=Y, XData=XData, XFormula=~x, distr="probit")

m = sampleMcmc(m, thin = thin, samples = samples, transient = transient,
               nChains = nChains, nParallel = nChains)

mpost = convertToCodaObject(m)
```

Then I want to try to predict into a raster, so I make a fake SpatRast dataset:

```r
library(terra)

x <- rast(nrows=100, ncols=100)

set.seed(2023)



values(x) <- rnorm(n = ncell(x))
names(x) <- "x"
```

You can see the spatraster here

[image]

Then I would like to predict the lone species prediction in this raster, so I have made several tries but here is my best try

## Best try

If I try this:

```r
Pred <- terra::predict(x, m, fun = Hmsc:::predict.Hmsc)
```

I get the following error:

```r
Error in sam$Beta : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any idea on how I could get this prediction right?

Comment: I would help if you showed how to make a prediction with `m` for a few values )(data.frame)  and how you would process the output (a list of length length(post)) to get one or more values for each input that you would like to get into the raster. Wrap that into a function and use that as `fun= ` in `terra::predict`

Comment: Thanks @RobertHijmans. I will Try that and edit it into the question